# How to add custom HTML to a Mechanize page object

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I was wondering if it was possible to add custom HTML code to a Mechanize page object. The goal is to avoid javascript code that creates a form, by adding the HTML generated by the javascript code to the mechanize page object (grabbed via the agent.get(uri) method) and having mechanize agent click on the submit form as if it really was there.
IT should be possible as the form is created directly on the page without any call to the outside except for a jpeg.
I cannot use Selenium and similars, I need to stick with Mechanize and Nokogiri.
Any help or even direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Please read "[ask]". What has your research showed you? If you haven't done any why not? If you have and it hasn't helped then show us where you searched and explain why that didn't help. Otherwise, please show us your minimal code showing your effort. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints would be good to read.

Comment: It's probably much easier to use Mechanize#post, which the form would call anyway.

Comment: @pguardiario I have tried that way also, but there is a string generated by the javascript that needs to be passed alongside the request.

Comment: Huh? You either have everything you need or you don't. If you have it, you can make the request. If you don't, nothing will work.

Answer (score 1):

Look at "[Scraping Data](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html#label-Scraping+Data)" in the Mechanize documentation. Because you can access and search the Nokogiri document you can modify it.

Modifying a document is easy with the Nokogiri used internally by Mechanize:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.example.org')
doc = page.parser
first_p = doc.at('p')
first_p.to_html                          # => "<p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>"
first_p.children = '
<form action="action_page.php">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="First name"><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last name"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>' 
first_p.to_html                          # => "<p>\n    <form action=\"action_page.php\">\n    First name:<br>\n    <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" value=\"First name\"><br>\n    Last name:<br>\n    <input type=\"text\" name=\"lastname\" value=\"Last name\"><br><br>\n    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">\n    </form></p>"
```

Looking up one level, to the parent:

```
page.parser.at('p').parent.to_html # => "<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>\n    <form action=\"action_page.php\">\n    First name:<br>\n    <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\" value=\"First name\"><br>\n    Last name:<br>\n    <input type=\"text\" name=\"lastname\" value=\"Last name\"><br><br>\n    <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">\n    </form></p>\n    <p><a href=\"http://www.iana.org/domains/example\">More information...</a></p>\n</div>"
```

Whether you can use Mechanize with the modified HTML is for you to figure out.

Comment: thank you, this is the direction I was looking for! I will try this and let you know whether I fail or succeed. That "is for you to figure out" makes me think it won't be that easy :D
Thank you for your time Tin Man!

Comment: No, it's because SO is not just a "help me get this done site", it also has a component of teaching. Good teachers don't show you how to do everything, they give you a nudge in the right direction and let you figure it out.

Comment: Still working on this, I have managed to insert and see the code inside my document, and then I am passing it to a new mechanize page with this line 
`page2 = Mechanize::Page.new(URI.parse('http://www.example.com'),{'content-type'=>'text/html'},doc.to_html,nil,agent)`
after this I am submitting the button but I keep receiving the same page, as if something went wrong, but I don't understand what. 
Is there a way to see what exactly am I sending in the request, or what is it lacking?